# add values to a form and send it to server using jquery submit

Tags: jquery, forms, post, get, submit

i have a form which  has

```
<button id="112" class="cc">EDIT</button>
```

so what i want to do is to use jquery submit function and send the id of button to server,  i know how to get the id of button , but sending a jquery variable to server i cant find a solution. this is what i have done so far

```
$('.button').click(function(){var dd=this.id; $('form').attr("edit.php");$('form').submit();
```

found on net there is submit(function) but how can i send variable dd to server, WITHOUT using AJAX. i want normal form submit

Answer (score 1):

Add it as a url varible

```
$('.button').click(function(){
      $('form').attr("action", "edit.php?id="+ this.id).submit();
});
```

Then retrieve it use GET , if you're using php it will be `$_GET['id']` .

Comment: There is no attribute `"edit.php?id="+ dd +""`; I guess it should be `.attr("action", "edit.php?id="+ dd +"");`

Comment: thank you for your reply, Im not quiet sure as why the url is not changing, this is how i declared the form <form method="get" action=""> </form> and my jquery script $(document).ready(function() {
$('.button').click(function(){
$('form').attr("action","edit.php?id="+ this.id).submit();
});
}); @shankarsangoli\ the url will be /edit.php?

Comment: and this is how i set up the button <button class="button" id="131231">Edit</button>

Comment: hmm , should work according to this test : http://jsfiddle.net/j7L5m/1/, take away the 'submit()' from the button and see what effect it has on the forms action param.